# Why am I getting an error when scheduling a query on Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

When trying to schedule a query in BQ, I am getting the following error:

Error code 3 : Query error: Not found: Dataset was not found in location EU at [2:1]

Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of the scheduled query being configured to run in a different region than either the referenced tables, or the destination table of the query.

Put another way, BigQuery requires a consistent location for reading and writing, and does not allow a query in location A to write results in location B.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries has some additional information about this.